# On improving the sensitivity of controlled experiments by utilizing pre-experiment data (CUPED)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stratification

I’m currently reading “[Improving the sensitivity of online controlled experiments by utilizing pre-experiment data](http://robotics.stanford.edu/people/ronnyk.link/2013-02CUPEDImprovingSensitivityOfControlledExperiments.pdf)” by Deng et al. and struggling to derive a few equations from the paper. I would appreciate some help from those who are familiar with the paper.

The first problem is with the first equation on page 4:

$$
\text{var}(\hat{Y}_\text{strat}) = \sum_{k = 1}^K \frac{w_k}{n} \sigma^2_k.
$$

It does not seem to match the one given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling):

$$
s_{\bar {x}}^{2}=\sum _{h=1}^{L}\left({\frac {N_{h}}{N}}\right)^{2}{\frac {s_{h}^{2}}{n_{h}}}.
$$

Presumably, $w_k = N_h/N$ and $\sigma^2_k = s_h^2/n_h$, but then $w_k$ is not squared, and the equation has an extra $n$ in the denominator.

The second problem is with equation 5 on the same page. How does one substitute

$$
\theta = \frac{\text{cov}(X, Y)}{\text{var}(X)}
$$

into

$$
\text{var}(\hat{Y}_\text{cv}) = \frac{1}{n}(\text{var}(Y) + \theta^2 \text{var}(X) - 2 \theta \text{cov}(X, Y))
$$

to get

$$
\text{var}(\hat{Y}_\text{cv}) = \text{var}(\bar{Y})(1 - \rho^2)?
$$

A sheet of paper and a pencil do not seem to help. Thank you!

Comment: First question: you were probably missing the definition of $n_k$ before equation (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question:

$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
Var(\hat{Y}_{strat}) &= Var(\sum_k w_k \bar{Y}_k) \\
&=\sum_k w_k^2 Var(\frac{1}{n_k}\sum Y^{(k)}_i) \\
&=\sum_k w_k^2 \frac{1}{n_k^2} n_k Var(Y^{(k)}_1)\\
&=\sum_k w_k^2 \frac{1}{n_k}\sigma_k^2\\
&=\sum w_k^2 \frac{1}{n w_k} \sigma_k^2\\
&=\sum w_k \frac{\sigma_k^2}{n}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
$

You were probably missing the definition of $n_k$ above equation (2).

Second question:

$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
Var(Y) + \theta^2 Var(X) -2\theta Cov(X,Y) &= Var(Y) + \frac{Cov^2(X,Y)}{Var^2(X)} Var(X) - 2\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)} Cov(X,Y)\\
&=Var(Y) - \frac{Cov^2(X,Y)}{Var(X)}\\
&=Var(Y)(1-\frac{Cov^2(X,Y)}{Var(X)Var(Y)})\\
&=Var(Y)(1-Corr^2(X,Y))
\end{split}
\end{align}
$

Then divide by $n$ to get the variance of the sample mean.

Comment: Right! In the first, I was indeed missing $n_k = w_k n$, and in the second, I actually got it, but for some reason, I failed to see it was correct. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Vote up and give me the bounty please.

Comment: Sure! It’s just not possible within 24 since the bounty start.